# MYSQL NOT IN array

Tags: php, mysql

need some help with a MYSQL call.
In one of my tables, I have an array (of sorts) of id's formatted likes this:
13,32,51,131,57 etc..

Every id is separated by a comma. Putting them in and getting them out I've figured out using explode and implode, but how would I go about searching through them direectly from the SQL call with php?

for example:
I need to see if id# 13 is in that row.

```
$this_id = '13';
$sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE this_id NOT IN ($this_id)";
```

So basically, I need to look through an array with NOT IN to see if the id number is in that array.
Any ideas?

Comment: Without knowing anything about your DB structure, all I can say is this: **don't put more than one piece of data in each column**. Your database should be [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: What @JamWaffles said. Packing loads of data into one field is really baaaaaadd

Comment: @DavidCaunt That Wikipedia page is getting worn out, I tell you! The amount of times I paste it around SO along with a comment. It's like the infamous multiple-ID issue people have with jQuery.

Comment: +1 to @JamWaffles; see also [Is storing a comma separated list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/)

Comment: @Bill I saw the link and instantly thought "yes". I'm a little bit confused as to why MySQL has aggregate functions to aid bad database design, however.

Comment: 8 good reasons not to rewrite a RDBMS in your application code. Great question to link to - thanks @BillKarwin

Comment: @JamWaffles: MySQL is full of its share of WTF's, like any product.

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks for posting that, I'll have to rethink how this data is stored.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as there are no more than 64 entries in your comma-separated list you can use the MySQL [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET( this_id, '$this_id' ) = 0
```

It's not clear to me whether the commas-separated array is your input data or stored in your table - so you may need to swap the arguments.

*(I should point out that constructing a query string using possibly tainted input exposes you to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.)*

Comment: Happy 20K rep, along with the privileges! I never knew MySQL had `FIND_IN_SET()` - thank you.

Comment: Another caveat to this method is that it's impossible to index.